# Finding $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\tan \theta - \tan^3 \theta}{\ln \tan \theta}$

Tags: integration

The original question was to evaluate:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-x}{(1+x) \ln x}\,dx$$

Using the substitution $x=\tan^2 \theta $, I simplified it down to the integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\tan \theta - \tan^3 \theta}{\ln \tan \theta}$.

From here, I am stuck and am not sure where to continue.

Comment: Maple produces $$-\ln  \left( \pi /2 \right)   .$$

Comment: @user64494. This is the good result but how to show it ? I am just totally stuck.

Answer (score 11):

Since:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n-x^{n+1}}{\log x}\,dx = \log\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right) \tag{1}$$
by [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html), by expanding $\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ as its Taylor series in zero, collecting terms of the form $(x^n-x^{n+1})$ and integrating termwise, we have that our integral just equals minus the logarithm of the [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product), hence $\color{red}{-\log(\pi/2)}$ as claimed.

Answer (score 7):

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-x}{(1+x) \ln x}\,dx=-\int_0^1\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k x^{y+k}\ dy \ dx=- \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_0^1\int_0^1  (-1)^k x^{y+k}\ dx \ dy$$
$$- \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \log\left(\frac{k+2}{k+1}\right)=-\log\left(\frac{2}{1}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{4}{3}\cdot \frac{4}{5}\cdot \frac{6}{5}\cdots\right)=-\log\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$$